# Add A UITableView Cell After Another One

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Essentially I have a tableview with two types of cells. One is a cell that contains a number that is being pulled from an array. The second cell is just supposed to act as a spacing cell but can contain information. However, I've only seen solutions that have the second cell come after the first if it its row is equal to 0 or if it is sectioned off.

The array of numbers is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and the first cell type pulls from it to display each number

I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

celltypeone: 1

celltypetwo

celltypeone: 2

celltypetwo

celltypeone: 3

celltypetwo

celltypeone: 4

celltypetwo

... and so on.

I thought about trying to get the space cell to come after every next cell but I didn't think that made sense.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let index = indexPath.row
  
   
    if index >= 0 {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productsblock", for: indexPath ) as! DetailTBCell


        return cell
     
    }
    else {
    
          let spacecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "spacingcell", for: indexPath ) as! DetailSpaceTBCell
        
        return spacecell

 
}
```

}

This prints all the numbers from the array and displays them but the second cell does not show at all.

I'm unsure of what to do or how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`if (index % 2) == 0` | try if index number is double put the first tableCell else put the other one

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let index = indexPath.row
  
   
    if (index % 2) == 0 {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productsblock", for: indexPath ) as! DetailTBCell


        return cell
     
    }
    else {
    
          let spacecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "spacingcell", for: indexPath ) as! DetailSpaceTBCell
        
        return spacecell

 
}
```

Comment: I've tried something similar. What happens is it does the first type of cell as every other. So it looks like 1 spacecell 3 spacecell 5 spacecell etc because its skipping the rest. However I'm trying to achieve a result where all elements of the array are returned and the spacing cell comes after each number in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your product cell needs to be shown at even position and the spacing cell at odd position.

```
`index >= 0 ` needs to replaced with `index % 2 == 0 `
```

Moreover in order to fetch data from product array you will be needing to divide the index by 2.

```
let products = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let index = indexPath.row


if index % 2 == 0 {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productsblock", for: indexPath ) as! DetailTBCell

    // Fetching data from array products defined above
    let data = products[index / 2]
    return cell
 
}
else {

      let spacecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "spacingcell", for: indexPath ) as! DetailSpaceTBCell
    
    return spacecell
```

}